# Hiding and revealing UIButtons

Tags: ipad

Hi all I am developing a app were in that if we press the UIButton it will show the hiding buttons and once we press the same Button hiding buttons will hide again!!!

I successfully made the hiding buttons to reveal by using the following code:`
    mapping1.hidden=NO;
    mapping2.hidden=NO;
    mapping3.hidden=NO;
but now i want to hide this buttons again by using the same button, how can i do that and if there any other possible way?

Comment: by the way, you need to accept answers to your previous questions, it is discouraging for people to put effort into answering your questions if you can't be bothered to accept their answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (mapping1.hidden)
{
    [mapping1 setHidden:NO];
    [mapping2 setHidden:NO];
    [mapping3 setHidden:NO];
}
else {
    [mapping1 setHidden:YES];
    [mapping2 setHidden:YES];
    [mapping3 setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make them hidden again, use

```
mapping1.hidden = YES;
```